# Pandas rounding

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rounding

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
Market Value
0  282024800.37
1  317460884.85
2 1260854026.24
3  320556927.27
4   42305412.79
```

I am trying to round the values in this dataframe to the nearest whole number.  Desired output:

```
Market Value

282024800
317460885
1260854026
320556927
42305413
```

I tried:

```
df.values.round()
```

and the result was

```
Market Value

282025000.00 
317461000.00 
1260850000.00 
320557000.00 
42305400.00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be more appropriate posted as a comment, but put here for proper format.

I can't produce your result. With numpy 1.18.1 and Pandas 1.1.0,

```
df.round().astype('int')
```

gives me:

```
   Market Value
0     282024800
1     317460885
2    1260854026
3     320556927
4      42305413
```

The only thing I can think of is that you may have a 32 bit system, where

```
df.astype('float32').round().astype('int')
```

gives me

```
   Market Value
0     282024800
1     317460896
2    1260854016
3     320556928
4      42305412
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will keep your data information intact as a float put will have it display/print to the nearest int.

**Big caveat:** it is only possible to have this apply to ALL dataframes at once (it is a pandas wide option) rather than just a single dataframe.

```
pd.set_option("display.precision", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like @noah's solution but don't want to only change the pandas display settings temporarily, you can use pandas's built-in context manager for this:

```
with pd.option_context('display.precision', 0):
    print(df)
```

and get

```
   Market value
0     282024800
1     317460885
2    1260854026
3     320556927
4      42305413
```